# Git status reports modified file on unmodified files

Tags: git, diff, carriage-return, line-endings

Any help with this problem would be appreciated. We are really out of ideas right now.

**Line ending setup**

My team is working in a mixed Linux/Windows environment so we've set up `git` to use `<LF>` line endings on Linux and `<CR><LF>` line endings on Windows, for text files. We use a `.gitattributes` file for this.

**Symptom**

Files that are unchanged are being reported by `git status` as "modified". This is only seen by two colleges, as far as I know.

The symptom shows mostly (maybe only) when we are programmatically generating the files involved. These files are `XML` files and they are known to be text files by `git`.

**Diagnosing the problem**

- Manual diff: To diagnose the problem, I've compared the files in the `git index` with those in the `working tree` in a hex editor. The only differences are the extra `<CR>` character in the working tree, as expected (see below).
- `git status` shows the files as "modified"
- `git diff <file>` shows no differences, as expected
- `git ls-files --eol <file>` shows `<LF>` in index and `<CR><LF>` in working tree and shows "text" attribute on `<file>`, as expected
- `git add <file>` does not change the index, as "expected" (there is no change).
- `git check-attr text <file>` shows text attribute is "set" (in the .gitattributes file).

Comment: if you are using eclipse, check the git settings in eclipse that might cause it to trip up. Also take a look at core.autocrlf setting, https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/, we had a problem with my team eclipse did not honor git/git bash settings on windows and so if eclipse was used to commit a file it used to mess up the whole diff.